# Ограничить вывод полей в связях Laravel

Tags: laravel

у меня есть Resource который возвращает инфу пользователя

```
class GetUser extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'            => $this->id,
            'name'          => $this->name,
            'surname'       => $this->surname,
            'about_as'      => $this->about_as,
            'avatar'        => $this->avatar,
            'role'          => $this->roles,
        ];
    }
}
```

Так же в roles подгружаются связи ролей у этого пользователя, все корректно выводится, но как ограничить к примеру у roles получить только поля id роли и name роли?

Comment: `->pluck('id')`, но запрос уже будет сделан

Comment: ещё можно попробовать `->lists('id')`, но я не уверен, не будет ли запрос выполнен ещё раз

Comment: Или создать отдельный класс респонса для ролей и вызывать его. Смотри документацию к респонсам, если не путаю

Comment: Спасибо, вот тоже рабочий пример ->map->only('id', 'name')